# Jlist, Deteting number of files

Tags: java, jlist, directory

Imagine that you have one folder with files and that folder appear on Jlist. What I want to know is, somehow, if the folder doesn't have any files it disappear of Jlist or simply don't appear.

```
 public static int displayDirectoryContents(File dir, String encontrarPasta) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        int count = 1;

        for (File file : files) {
            String s = file.getPath().substring(file.getPath().lastIndexOf(File.separator)+1);
            if(!(getFileCount(file, encontrarPasta)==0)){
            if (file.isDirectory()){

                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(encontrarPasta)) {
                    listModel.addElement(file);
                    break;
                } else {

                    count +=  displayDirectoryContents(file, encontrarPasta);

                }
            }
}
            }
        return count;

    }
```

I'm trying to do like this, first counting and appear on console how many the folder have, the next step is say to the program that the folder that returns "0" files don't appear on Jlist Items....But for now, i'm not being sucesseful.

Comment: Your question is unclear, at least to me. You should probably rephrase and add some code

Comment: @Dici it helped? i tried to explain better

Comment: Sorry I'll take a look later, I'm busy right now. Hopefully some other people will also read your question